# Is there a science-based book on how to handle mealtime with fussy toddlers?

Tags: toddler, behavior, eating

I want to learn about what's effective and what's not when it comes to getting a toddler to eat. I prefer a book based on science/data rather than anecdotes/opinions. Does anyone know of such a book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a bibliography to get you started. If your local library does not have any of these, they are readily available through interlibrary loan (US), or your librarian may ask the library to purchase (newer titles) for you, or the librarian may recommend a similar title that they do have. These books will be found in the Dewey Decimal system under 618.92 (pediatric health).

- Boakes, Robert A, David A. Popplewell, and Michael J. Burton. *Eating
  Habits: Food Physiology, and Learned Behaviour*. Chichester: Wiley, 1987.  A series of articles, including:  The Acquisition of Food Acceptance Patterns in Children - Signals Determining Meal Size -
  Cognitive Experimental Psychology of Appetite
- Piette, Linda D. *Just Two More Bites!: Helping Picky Eaters Say "yes"
  to Food*. New York: Three Rivers Press, 2006.  Contents:  Solving the
  puzzle of picky eating -- Understanding growth -- Feeding skills --
  Fussy babies -- Fussy toddlers and preschoolers -- How much nutrition
  is enough? -- Making food desirable -- Food textures and flavors --
  Family influences -- Mealtime do's and don'ts -- Food allergies and
  digestion problems -- Feeding a chlid with special needs -- Special
  services, tests and treatments.
- Wilkoff, William G. *Coping with a Picky Eater: A Guide for the
  Perplexed Parent*. New York: Fireside, 1998. Contents: Have You Picked
  Up the Right Book? --; Before You Read Another Word... --; A Few
  Ounces of Prevention --; Not So Great Expectations --; Not to Worry
  --; Getting Ready to Take the Leap --; Assembling Your Support Group --; Do You Need to Change Your Parenting Style? --; Everyone Needs Some Rules --; When the Rules Are Challenged --; If You Push --; Does
  Your Child Have a Drinking Problem? --; Too Much of a Good Thing --;
  A Banquet Once a Day ... Every Day --; Just Desserts (or Never Say
  Never) --; So Now What Do You Offer? --; Getting Down to Basics --;
  Suggested Menus --; Vitamins and Other Bad Ideas --; Some Final
  Thoughts.
- *Healthy Eating for Life for Children*. New York: Wiley, 2002. From the
  Physicians Committee for Responsible Medicine. Drawing on the latest
  medical and dietary research, Healthy Eating for Life for Children
  presents a complete and sensible plant-based nutrition program that
  can help you promote and maintain excellent health and good eating
  habits for your children throughout their lives.
- Fish, Donna. *Take the Fight Out of Food: How to Prevent and Solve
  Your Child's Eating Problems : for Children Aged Nine Months Through
  Nine Years*. New York: Atria Books, 2005. Presents guidelines for
  parents on how to instill healthy eating habits throughout childhood,
  counseling them on how to teach nutrition-based values and recognize
  messages that a family may be unconsciously teaching children.
- Kleinman, Ronald E, Michael S. Jellinek, and Julie Houston. *Let Them
  Eat Cake!: The Case against Controlling What Your Children Eat : the
  Pediatrician's Guide to Safe and Healthy Food and Growth*. New York:
  Villard Books, 1994. The premise of this book is that if a child is
  healthy and his or her growth and development are normal there is no
  need to obsess about the food that child eats. Contains hints and
  tips about real-world food and nutrition, including meal plans,
  menus, and the latest information on food safety and preparation.
- Pantley, Elizabeth. *The No-Cry Picky Eater Solution: Gentle Ways to
  Encourage Your Child to Eat and Eat Healthy*. New York: McGraw-Hill,
  Contents: What you really need to know about picky eaters -- The fundamental four: attitude, environment, amounts, and rules --
  Tips, tricks and tactics: Solving picky eater problems -- The
  experts' favorites: Recipes even your picky eater will love
- Drewett, Robert. *The Nutritional Psychology of Childhood.* Cambridge:
  Cambridge University Press, 2007. The Nutritional Psychology of
  Childhood is a systematic account of research on the psychological
  aspects of nutrition in children from birth to adolescence. It deals
  with two major themes: the development of eating and the effects of
  malnutrition on the developing child. Robert Drewett discusses the
  developmental problems that arise with eating and food intake,
  including nursing and weaning in infancy, the handling of solids and
  the development of food choice and eating habits.
- Jana, Laura A, and Jennifer Shu. *Food Fights: Winning the Nutritional
  Challenges of Parenthood Armed with Insight, Humor and a Bottle of
  Ketchup*. Elk Grove Village, IL: American Academy of Pediatrics, 2012.
  From the American Academy of Pediatrics. The authors tastefully blend
  the science of nutrition and pediatrics with the practical insights
  of parents who have been in your shoes―offering simple solutions for
  your daily nutritional challenges.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This is a way better answer than I could have hoped for.

Comment: Hurray for librarians! :)

Comment: I'm surprised there's no [Ellyn Satter](http://www.ellynsatter.com/curriculum-vitae-i-85.html) on this list. Her book [Child of Mine](http://www.ellynsatter.com/physical-products-books-child-of-mine-feeding-with-love-and-good-sense-p-786.html) was highly recommended to me by a pediatrician and while some of her information is surely out of date, her division of responsibilities in feeding have appeared in several things I've read about food. She provides a lot of anecdotes, but as an RD her information is based on her training.

Comment: @justkt The list I created was certainly not comprehensive - it contains books catalogued by libraries as Children-Nutrition-Psychological Aspects, and is limited to books that are in at least 200 libraries (so easily obtainable). The book you suggest is very popular (over 400 libraries have it cataloged), and it has a 2000 update. It is cataloged as Child Nutrition - Popular Works, so it wasn't included in my search -  your personal recommendation is very valuable!